# Require username and pass when downloading file with wamp server

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

How can I restrict users from downloading files from wamp server?

In other words if I place a file at my www root directory at  www\someSecureFolder\file1.pdf  when a user goes to "ip address"\someSecureFolder\file1.pdf I don't want to enable him to download that file unless he is authenticated in some way. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to password protect that folder using Apache.  The easiest way would be through an .htaccess file.  Follow [this post](http://sniptools.com/vault/windows-apache-and-htaccess-authentication).  Make sure you Apache conf allows for .htaccess files to be read.